# The 'true' value is string, but the 'false' value is tuple

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to print the values based on the boolean value. For some reason, It errors out

my local.tf file is the following:

```
locals {
  test = true
  non_test = true
  domains = [
    { name: "testing-1",
      id: "SWT1",
      building: "D1"
    },
    {  name: "testing-2",
      id: "SWT2",
      building: "D2"
     },
    {  name: "testing-3",
      id: "SWT3",
      building: "D3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error

```
> local.test && local.non_test ? local.domains[0].name : local.domains[*].name
╷
│ Error: Inconsistent conditional result types
│
│   on <console-input> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The 'true' value is string, but the 'false' value is tuple.
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `local.domains[0].name` and `local.domains[*].name` are not the same type. `The true and false result expressions must have consistent types`

Comment: @DusanBajic: I would like to print.   ``` local.test && local.non_test ? local.domains[0].name : local.domains```

Comment: Well, you cannot do that as per the error.

Comment: @Datta Did you modify your code as advised? Does the issue still persist?

Comment: We are good now. I was able to deploy the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two lists, or two strings, in your conditions, but not a mixture of them. I think lists would be better, so it would be:

```
local.test && local.non_test ? [local.domains[0].name] : local.domains[*].name
```